# WebService API for Order containing Deleted product

Tags: c#, rest, prestashop

I am trying to build a C# API for interacting with the Prestashop WebService API, I am making a request to my site for an order.

http://prestashop.dev.local/api/orders/4

Inside this order 1 of the products has since been deleted

http://prestashop.dev.local/api/products/7

when I attempt to load that product from the API I get a 403  (Forbidden).

Is this the correct response for a deleted product (ie Should I just handle the 403 and assume the product has been deleted)? Or is there something else I should have done?

I have posted this to the [Prestashop forums](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/244958-webservice-api-for-order-containing-deleted-product/), but wasn't sure if it would get answered as on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Products are kept in orders even if deleted for history purpose (to print the invoice for instance).

But you cannot access directly to deleted products ... because they are deleted.

A Not Found (404) or Gone (410) HTTP code should be more appropriate. Forbidden is confusing here.

In addition, the product's id could be set to null in orders when deleted, to prevent to link to it.

Maybe some improvements to send to the PrestaShop team.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, 404 would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Even if the products have been deleted, informations are always stored in the order.

403 is an error which mean you have a configuration problem and Prestashop can't execute the request.